# How to summarise pam clustering results in R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, dplyr

If i try to run the code below to get the summary of my clustering results, I get the following error:

> `Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : no applicable method for 'mutate_'
>   applied to an object of class "table"`

This code works if dat_ is a data frame, but if it is a table is get the above error message. Does anyone have a solution?

```
    pam_fit <- pam(gower_dist, diss = TRUE, k)  # performs cluster analysis
    pam_results <- dat %>%
      mutate(cluster = pam_fit$clustering) %>%
      group_by(cluster) %>%
      do(the_summary = summary(.))
    pam_results$the_summary
```

Sample data set:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(ID = rep(sample(c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g"),10,replace = TRUE),70),
                 disease = sample(c("flu","headache","pain","inflammation","depression","infection","chest pain"),100,replace = TRUE))

dat <- unique(dat)

dat2 <- table(dat)
dat3 <- as.data.frame(dat)
```

Comment: of course, you may use `as.data.frame(dat)`, but make sure you didn't lose something during this transfer, especially the column names.

Comment: Unfortunately that gives another error: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `cluster` must be length 707851 (the number of rows) or one, not 1783

Comment: From [here](https://dpmartin42.github.io/posts/r/cluster-mixed-types) `length(pam_fit$clustering)=nrow(college_clean)`. Therefore, make sure `nrow(dat)` is equal to `length(pam_fit$clustering)`

Comment: Yup as I said, `length(pam_fit$clustering)` is not equal to `nrow(dat3)` hence `mutate` will through an error. You need to find a way to join these two things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at dat, every ID has multiple observations, and you are trying to partition ID into clusters, based on their disease column. So your cluster results should be as long as your id, and if you want to summarize your results, you do it per cluster.

To put the tables together, do:

```
library(cluster)
library(tidyverse)

pam_fit <- pam(daisy(dat2,"gower"), diss = TRUE, 2)  # performs cluster analysis

pam_results <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(dat)) %>%
mutate(cluster = pam_fit$clustering) %>%
group_by(cluster) %>%
do(the_summary = summary(.),freq = colSums(.))
```

This gives the summary:

```
pam_results$freq
[[1]]
  chest pain   depression          flu     headache    infection inflammation 
           4            5            4            3            5            3 
        pain      cluster 
           5            5 

[[2]]
  chest pain   depression          flu     headache    infection inflammation 
           1            2            2            2            2            2 
        pain      cluster 
           0            4
```

If you just need the frequency, you can simply do:

```
aggregate(as.data.frame.matrix(dat2[,-1]),list(cluster=pam_fit$clustering),sum)
      cluster depression flu headache infection inflammation pain
    1       1          5   4        3         5            3    5
    2       2          2   2        2         2            2    0
```

Or a dplyr solution:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(dat2[,-1]) %>% 
mutate(cluster=pam_fit$clustering) %>%
group_by(cluster) %>%
summarize_all(sum)

# A tibble: 2 x 7
  cluster depression   flu headache infection inflammation  pain
    <int>      <int> <int>    <int>     <int>        <int> <int>
1       1          5     4        3         5            3     5
2       2          2     2        2         2            2     0
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I haven't had time to work on this. Anyway, when I use your solution  the second column in the dataframe contains text like this: c("Min. :1 ", "1st Qu.:1 ", "Median :1 ", "Mean :1 ", "3rd Qu.:1 ". What I would like to see, however, are the names of the diseases with their frequencies. Is that possible?

Comment: if you want a frequency, what you need is not a summary but a sum. see edited answer